# Impossible to create the root directory - swagger with laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to add swagger documentation on my laravel rest API. First of all, I have installed the `composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger"` and then `composer require zircote/swagger-php` then I have run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

but the follwuing error occures.

```
   League\Flysystem\Exception  : Impossible to create the root directory "". 

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\landing-temp\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php:112
    108|             clearstatcache(false, $root);
    109| 
    110|             if ( ! is_dir($root)) {
    111|                 $errorMessage = isset($mkdirError['message']) ? $mkdirError['message'] : '';
  > 112|                 throw new Exception(sprintf('Impossible to create the root directory "%s". %s', $root, $errorMessage));
    113|             }
    114|         }
    115|     }
    116| 

  Exception trace:

  1   League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local::ensureDirectory()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\landing-temp\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php:78

  2   League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local::__construct()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\landing-temp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand.php:235

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: make sure your directory have correct permissions.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz Thanks, but how can I do that in windows 10?

Comment: if you are on windows then seems like a symlink issue

Comment: yes, it's windows, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger`**
For use of @SWG annotation we are going to install the following package,

**`composer require zircote/swagger-php`**

and then run this artisan command,

**`php artisan vendor:publish --provider 'L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider'`**

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 8.  Documentation says that it uses a package auto-discovery feature. But it's not true.

You have to add to your config/app.php in providers section:

```
L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider::class,
```

Then, you have to run the

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And only then, you can run the

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider 'L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider'
```

Answer (score 1):

*Versions: Laravel 6, darkaonline/l5-swagger : "6.*"*

**Just add this line in your .env file**

```
L5_SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS=true
```

**Then run this command**

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**At the end run this command**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

check your read/write permissions:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#directory-permissions

as root:

```
cd /dir/to/your/laravel-app
chmod -R 750 .
chmod -R 770 ./storage
chmod -R 770 ./bootstrap/cache
```

And what also worked me after I checked the permissions: `php artisan config:cache` [source](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/274) or for laravel versions > 7 `php artisan optimize`